# Como exibir determinada posição de um array associativo?

Tags: php, array

Este é o meu *array* associativo:

```
$vetor = array(
 "Nome"=> "posicao1",
 "Telefone"=> "posicao2",
 "Idade"=> "posicao3",
 "Sexo"=> "posicao4"
);
```

Para exibir o conteúdo dele posso utilizar o `foreach()`;

```
foreach($vetor as $campo => $valor){
    echo "Na posicao ".".$campo_echo." está o: ".$valor."<br>";
}
```

Mas, e se eu quiser exibir apenas os dois valores? E seu eu quiser exibir somente três valores? Como posso fazer isso?

Tentei utilizar o `for`, mas sem sucesso:

```
for($i=0; $i<=1; $i++){
 echo $vetor[$i];
}
```

Comment: `echo $vetor[3] .'-'.  $vetor[2];` isso?, no segundo exemplo `$i` deve começar em `1`

Comment: seu count vai ser dependente de quantos valores vc quer setar, começando ou terminando no seu valor setado em $i

Comment: Quando dizes _"exibir apenas os dois valores"_ sabes quais são as chaves desses dois valores?

Comment: Este dois exemplos que vocês me deram funciona somente quando eu coloco números nas chaves, ´1`, `2` etc. Modifiquei o código para exemplificar o que quero fazer. Digamos que eu queira exibir somente os três primeiros campos: os valores de `nome`, `telefone` e ìdade`. Usaria o `for`, correto?

Comment: Este exemplo echo $vetor[0] .'-'. $vetor[1] .....;` funciona. Porém, se meu array tiver 100, 200, 300 elementos, fazer isso de um a um não é uma boa prática, logo tenho que automatizar isso. Daí, entra o `for`. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Minha sugestão foi baseada nas informações da pergunta, na primeira versão eram indices números agora são associativos e também não foi comentado sobre 100 ou 300 indices/chaves, não deu para entender direito o q vc quer, o segundo comentário parece ser a solução.

Comment: Eu deixei com números para exemplificar, não sabia que deixando as chaves com números as mesmas são consideradas como índices. Como disse, se meu array tiver 300 chaves/elementos e que queira exibir somente os primeiros 250, como posso fazer isso? Esta é a minha dúvida. A diferença é que o exemplo que fiz é bem menor, eu quero exibir o indice 0 e 1, ou seja, os dois primeiros. Perdão se me expressei mal.

Comment: A pergunta desde o início era um *array* associativo. Eram *strings*. Mesmo que fossem numéricos, ainda assim poderia ser um *array* associativo. As chaves deste tipo de *array* podem ser de qualquer tipo.

Comment: `$vetor = array(
 "Nome"=> "posicao1",
 "Telefone"=> "posicao2",
 "Idade"=> "posicao3",
 "Sexo"=> "posicao4"
);`

Como eu faço para exibir somente os dois primeiros campos com um `for`?

Comment: `for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){ echo $vetor[$i]."<br>"; }`. Ou, no primeiro `$i` tricando o `1` por `0` e o `3` por `2`, tamém não funciona :/

Comment: @LuizSantos A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Você faz isto com a função [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
foreach (array_keys($vetor) as $index => $key) echo $index . ": " . $key . " => " . $vetor[$key] . "\n";

$array = array_keys($vetor);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++) echo $array[$i] . " => " . $vetor[$array[$i]] . "\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/j7OEqg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iyhpwzty-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/KeyValue.php).

Comment: Com o `foreach` eu exibo TODOS os elementos do meu `array`. Digamos que eu queira exibir somente os dois primeiros ementos do `array` ou somente os três primeiros. Como posso fazer isso dentro de um `for` ou de alguma estrutura de loop?

Answer (score 1):

Esse laço de repetição itera o array inteiro e exibe a chave associativa e o seu respectivo valor.

```
foreach ($vetor as $k => $v) {
    echo $k.' -> '.$v.PHP_EOL.'<br>';
}
```

Caso queria exibir um range determinado, pode apenas criar condicionais dentro do laço de repetição.

Exemplo, se pretende exibir somente o segundo e o terceiro

```
$c = 1;
foreach ($vetor as $k => $v) {
    if ($c == 2 || $c == 3) {
        echo $k.' -> '.$v.PHP_EOL.'<br>';
    }
    $c++;
}
```

Mas dependendo do caso pode não ser muito bom, pois ainda estaria iterando o array inteiro.

Poderia fazer de outro modo para poupar recursos de memória e processamento. Mesmo que seja uma economia pequena. O mais interessante é que torna a rotina mais dinâmica, ou seja, reutilizável:

```
$arr = array(
    'Nome'=> 'posicao1',
    'Telefone'=> 'posicao2',
    'Idade'=> 'posicao3',
    'Sexo'=> 'posicao4'
);


function foo($arr, $ini, $end) {
    // O terceiro parâmetro como true, preserva os índices.
    return array_slice($arr, $ini-1, $end-1, true);
}

// Isso aqui retorna o array "cortado" definindo parâmetros de forma mais simplificada.
$arr = foo($arr, 2, 3);

// Itera tudo normalmente sem precisar fazer firula.
// O laço de repetição fica "livre" de condicionais.
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    echo $k.' -> '.$v.PHP_EOL.'<br>';
}

/*
[retorno]
Telefone -> posicao2 
Idade -> posicao3
*/
```

Saliento que cada solução depende da situação. Num array maior, por exemplo, mais de 20 ítens, acredito melhor o slice. Num array menor, faça como no primeiro exemplo com condicional dentro do laço de repetição.